Monday.com get column value
I'm trying to fetch data from monday.com API but I'm not getting the values for mirror or board relations as I would need.
My query:
{
    "query": "{ boards(ids: [XXXXXX]) { items_page(limit: 1) { cursor items { id name column_values { id text value column { id type title settings_str } } } } } }"
}

Example output:
{
    "id": "mirror_1",
    "text": null,
    "value": null,
    "column": {
        "id": "mirror_1",
        "type": "mirror",
        "title": "Title of column",
        "settings_str": "{\"relation_column\":{\"connect_boards3\":true},\"displayed_column\":{\"numbers\":true},\"displayed_linked_columns\":{\"215429408\":[\"numbers\"]}}"
    }
},

What I would need I just the value of the mirror_1 but it returns null even if it has a value.
What should I do?

I found the answer after more investigation:
{
  "query": "{ boards(ids: [XXXXXX]) { items_page(limit: 1) { cursor items { id name column_values { id type text value ... on MirrorValue { mirrored_items { linked_item { id name column_values { id text }} } } } } } } }"
}

... on MirrorValue was the solution.
